How can I force a A/B test variant to load live?
I am trying to evaluate some things on a production A/B test and need to see the variant experience. However, I cannot get it to load despite it being live. No amount of cache clearing or incognito will make it pop for me. Is there a way to force load the variant live?
Apologies if its not clear what Im asking.

Can you provide an example? Screenshots help.

You can preview your live A/B test variant by reloading the concerned page a few times while browsing it in Incognito mode and/or clearing Sitecore cookies between attempts.
Note, that sc_test_combination cookie stores information about the test variant used on the current page.
Read more here about cookies used by Sitecore.
If you always see the default variant only and your alternative variant never appears then it is a sign of possible misconfiguration of Sitecore XP. If you are in doubts then make sure that your test page and its related content are published, then check your CD config ensuring that the key settings: xDB.Enabled, xDB.Tracking.Enabled and ContentTesting.Enable are enabled and set to true.
